# ajax - send and receive data error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to get a send and received ajax coding, but im getting an error that preco is not an index in Complista2 page. This is the code:

the starting page:

```
$(function() {      
        $("#b1").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "complista2.php",
                data: $("#preco").val(),                
                success: $.get("complista2.php", function(data) {
                    $("#paramount").html(data);
                })
            });
        }); 
    });

<input id="preco" type="text" name="preco" value='250 AND 500'><br><br>
```

This is the Complista2 page:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$server = "localhost";
$database = "VRealidade";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Erro: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {    
    }

$preco = $_GET['preco'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM computadores WHERE preco BETWEEN $preco"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo mysqli_error($conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<div class='entrada'>$row[nome]</div>"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div class='entrada'>$row[nome]</div>";
}       

?>
```

EDIT : This is the form, but it bears no implication in this code.

```
<form id="pesqmenu2" method='GET'>
    <input id="preco" type="text" name="preco" value='250 AND 500'>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it? The only thing you send as data is a value; there's no reason to expect it would be a parameter named `"preco"` that I can see.

Comment: eh, uhm... `$.get()` doesn't return a function that can be used by the success option.

Comment: @Dave Newton @ Kevin B  Thanks for the answer, guys. But could give some tips for a solution? im still learning, you know.

Comment: Little try change GET BY POST  $preco = $_POST['preco']; var_dump($preco); exit();   result is null or no?

Comment: @headmax its null

Comment: Here add an alert like this $("#b1").click(function() { alert($("#preco").val()); ...    and show us the page form. What the result?

Comment: @headmax the alert gives out "250 AND 500", but i cant get it to complista2. It still gives that it is an undefined index there.

Comment: Look at the ajax it was the problem and you use 2 different methods into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. All i had to do was to add this inside the click event :

```
$.post("Complista2.php/?preco="+$("#preco").val(), function(data) {
        $("#paramount").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$server = "localhost";
$database = "VRealidade";
$html = "";

//check if preco initialized, and filter for default and special chars as SQL injection ...
if(isset($_POST['preco']) && filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'preco', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)) {

  try {
    $preco = $_POST['preco'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_error()) {
      $error = "MySQLi error " . mysqli_error() . ": " . mysqli_error() . "\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$query\n<br>";
      exit();
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM computadores WHERE preco BETWEEN $preco";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $html .= "<div class='entrada'>$row[nome]</div>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $html .= "<div class='entrada'>$row[nome]</div>";
    }

    //ouput html
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($html);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception reçue : ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

You need to change your form is your problem is dont send to page .php

```
<form id="pesqmenu2" name="pesqmenu2" method="post">
  <input id="preco" type="text" name="preco" value='250 AND 500'>
  <input type="submit" id="b1" name="b1" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Ajax changed :

```
$(function() {   
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "complista2.php",
        data: { preco: $("#preco").val() }
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $("#paramount").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: it still gives out that preco is an undefined index in complista2

Comment: And the alert give you any error?, the status of the post in the console is 200? the post variable exist on the list you show preco?

Comment: the alert gives out "250 AND 500". The variable exists in the database. The problem is that it preco  doesnt reach complista2

Comment: the complista2 on the console is called with 200 status header?

Comment: ok the response json isn't figured now it is. look at the script change at //output html dont forget you need on your page a element with id paramount is where the html ouput from php go to parse inside #paramount